# Print multidimensional array in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a multidimensional array to keep strings in it, with a length of 5. However it seems to be problem when i try to print out a sinle element from the arrays.

In my `printf("%s", a[0][0][5])` it should print out "hej0" in a `char array` last `[5]`stand for the amout of characters of the current element + '\o' And first and second `[]` stand for row and which element to target?

When i try to compile this code it will just crash.

```
int main() {

    char a[3][4][5] = {
        {"hej0", "hej1", "hej2", "hej3"} ,
        {"hej4", "hej5", "hej6", "hej7"} ,
        {"hej8", "hej9", "hej10", "hej11"}
        };

    printf("%s", a[0][0][5]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Problem sloved, well done

Comment: Note that some of your strings are too long for the array dimensions (your compiler should be warning you about this!) - you really need `char a[3][4][6]` since you have some 5 character strings which need 6 bytes including terminator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do :

```
printf("%s", a[0][0][5]);
```

You are trying to access the 6th character of the string pointed by `a[0][0]`, which is `"hej0"`.
It has 4 characters and the fifth is the NULL terminating byte `\0` (so you are trying to read beyond the string).

To print `"hej0"`:

```
printf("%s", a[0][0]);
```

Comment: `a[0][0][5]` is the 6th character, which is the first after `'\0'`

Answer (score 3):

First issue I have seen your code is that size of array should be `a[3][4][6]` not `a[3][4][5]`.
Because your elements `"hej10"`, `"hej11"` required 6 bytes instead of 5.
Also to print any particular element just provide base address like:

```
printf("%s", a[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

First problem is, if you want to put a 5 char string into a char array, you need to make the array 6 chars big, as it is terminated by character `'\0'`.

Second problem is, `a[0][0][5]` is the sixth element of the third row, which does not exist.

Third problem would be, if you want to print the complete string you should not specify a char number for output. Try `a[0][0]` instead of `a[0][0][5]`

Here is a correction:

```
char a[3][4][6] = {
    { "hej0", "hej1", "hej2", "hej3" },
    { "hej4", "hej5", "hej6", "hej7" },
    { "hej8", "hej9", "hej10", "hej11"}
};

printf("%s", a[0][0]);
```